# Uniform convergence of series of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions

Consider the sequence of functions
$\left(f_n\right)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ where
$$f_n(x)=\ln\left(\frac{x}{n} +1\right),\qquad n\in \mathbb{N}.$$

How do I prove that this sequence of functions does not converge uniformly on $[0,+\infty[$ ?

The sequence obviously converges pointwise at $x=0$, for,
if $f_n(0)=0, \;\forall n\geq 1$.

Comment: if $x>0$, then $f_n(x)$ is a real number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sequence converges pointwise to the null function. If the convergence was uniform, there would be some $N\in\Bbb N$ such that$$(\forall x\in[0,\infty)):n\geqslant N\implies\left|\log\left(\frac xn+1\right)\right|<1.$$But$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N):\left|\log\left(\frac{e\cdot n}n+1\right)\right|=\log(e+1)>1.$$

Comment: Thank you, so the sequence doesn't converge uniformly on compact subintervals of $[0,+\infty[$ either?

Comment: Quite the opposite. It converges uniformly on *every* compact subinterval of $[0,\infty)$.